# Set a header in middleware node.js express framework

Tags: node.js, express

I have a middleware doing some auth. In this auth-method I need to set a response header.

```
server.get('/api/users, auth(), getUsers);
```

My authmethod:

```
module.exports = (isProduction) => {
  return function(req, res, next){
     ...

     next();

  }
}
```

How do I attach a header in this auth function?

Comment: I changed the name of the title to include express and added the tag as the .`get()`, and `(req, res, next)` indicate this is likely an expressjs question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume you are using `express.js`. In express, there is a `set` function (documentation [here](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.set). You can use it like this

```
res.set('<header name>', '<header value>')
```

before calling `next()`

Comment: This answer implies in node.js core you can call `.set()` on the `http.response` object — it does not have that method. Closest thing would be: `response.setHeader(name, value) ala
`response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');`

Comment: @adamrights It is an `express.js` related question (see the tag used by the OP). And there is a `set` function [here](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.set)

Comment: The OP never included Express.js in the title. I edited this after fact and it was recently accepted.

Comment: My bad, so I assumed it. But it seems that it helps the OP

Comment: All good. Looks like people can find useful information here and that's what counts.

Answer (score 4):

How you actually use it as middleware.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('access-control-allow-origin', '*');
    next()
})
```

Comment: this is the only answer that actually shows a middleware, which was the original question

Answer (score 2):

This is not a `node.js` core question but rather a question on `express.js`.

In that case your reference is: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.set

The set() function's signature is: `res.set(field [, value])`

The `res` object is a wrapper around node's native `http.response` api.

You can call `.set()` multiple times in express.js middleware as long as they occur before the `next()` function is invoked, which calls the following middleware in the chain.

There is nothing special about next(). But if the following middleware writes the headers, by calling res.send() or even res.redirect(), then one can no longer set the headers.

You can call set multiple times, and you can use an object to pass multiple headers, as in the documentation example:

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');

res.set({
  'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
  'Content-Length': '123',
  'ETag': '12345'
});
```

Comment: This is my answer. Thx